# Как включить нормальное отображение цифр в VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Что-то случайно нажал (какое-то сочетание клавиш) и теперь все цифры в дебагере показываются вот так:
[image: hex отображение цифр]

Как отключить это и сделать, чтобы 1 было 1, а не 0х00000001?

Comment: В контекстном меню отключите шестнадцатеричный режим отображения.

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно, не заметил его даже, спасибо! Можете оформить как ответ :)